# Memory is not released after a executing queries with SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I get that: The process is terminated with all the records in database inserted, then when I see the task manager in Windows the sqlserver.exe process still have a 3.663.263mb occupying my in memory and is not released.......

Comment: SQL Server is going to use as much memory as it wants (and hold on to) unless you specifically tell it to never consume x amount.

Comment: To add to what @TyCobb said, if you want SQL Server to release some of its memory, you'd have to restart the service, reboot the host server, or manually configure the `MAX SERVER MEMORY` setting to a value lower that what you are seeing in task manager.  The only other time SQL will release memory (that I know of), is when the Resource Monitor determines OS level memory availability is low (via WinAPI [QueryMemoryResourceNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

You can control the server memory configuration and set `MAX SERVER MEMORY`. here is a good overview document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx

Minimum Maximum Memory Values are : 32bit - 64MB  64bit - 128mb

> Set min server memory and max server memory to span a range of memory
>   values. This method is useful for system or database administrators to
>   configure an instance of SQL Server in conjunction with the memory
>   requirements of other applications that run on the same computer.
>
> Use min server memory to guarantee a minimum amount of memory
>   available to the SQL Server Memory Manager for an instance of SQL
>   Server. SQL Server will not immediately allocate the amount of memory
>   specified in min server memory on startup. However, after memory usage
>   has reached this value due to client load, SQL Server cannot free
>   memory unless the value of min server memory is reduced.